# Rake aborting with Devise installation on Ruby - cannot migrate the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rake

I'm trying my hands on Ruby on Rails and needed to set up a simple authentication using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). I followed the instructions however I'm constantly getting the following error:

```
>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

I get this error every time I try to run `rake db:migrate` - the migrate file does exist in the db/migrate folder but it wont proceed further. Please help.

Comment: Can you specify which version of rails and what environment you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Run the rake command in trace mode, and the error will become visible.

```
rake db:migrate --trace
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove **devise_for :users** line from routes.rb file then try to run rake db:migrate.